# Is it possible to add an attribute of Object with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, object, attributes

In JavaScript, I can create a new object (called clean). Then if I want to set an attribute of that object I just set objectName.attributeName = whatever. Is it possible to do something similar in C#, **WITHOUT** defining a class?

---

```
var clean = new Object();
clean.isClean = true;
```

Comment: `dynamic` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

Comment: And I'm voting to close because this really could have been found rather easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since .NET 4.0 yes, you can using `ExpandoObject`:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.text = "hello world";
```

Anyway, if you're just looking to create objects *on-the-fly*, you should use an anonymous type declaration:

```
var obj = new { text = "hello world" };
```

Actually, expando objects have an added value: you can also add methods using delegates. For example:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.DoIt = new Action
(
    () => 
    {
        // Code here
    }
);

expando.DoIt();
```

Comment: Do you have some documentation? I'm interested in learning about this `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: @jsve Maybe this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx

Comment: @jsve: Did you try *looking* for the documentation? Just a search for `ExpandoObject` finds it for me - and adding .net or msdn to the search finds it even more cleanly.

Comment: @JonSkeet In fact, this is what I did to give him an article :P

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I find that links to documentation often lead to more informative posts, that is why I asked for it.

Comment: @jsve Check this http://tinyurl.com/ot7pw2v !! :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I'm so glad you used this workaround. I, for one, found it funny. I've been reading a whole bunch of Meta posts about how people think that LMGTFY is offensive. I think it's plain funny. Thanks for "bypassing the system" :).

Comment: @jsve hahaha yeah it's very funny. I remember when someone gave me a link to this site a long time ago in IRC... :D